# Prove that the given series of functions is continuously differentiable.

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, uniform-convergence

$f(x)= \Sigma_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {\sin nx^2}{1+n^3}$, $x\in {\mathbb{R}}$

I can show continuity by using uniform convergence and the Weierstrass M test. But I don't know how to do differentiability. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Is that $f(x)= \Sigma_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {\sin nx^2}{1+n^3}$ or did I get this wrong?

Comment: @Mohammad Zuhair Khan That's right.

Comment: Should I edit your question to give the equation in $\LaTeX$ or did you give the image on purpose?

Comment: @Mohammad Zuhair Khan I am using a mobile. So I'm not very comfortable using MathJax on phone. Hence the image.

Comment: Even me but I think the community _in general_ prefers $\LaTeX$ over images. So, should I edit your question. Takes only $5$ seconds. BTW are you using the app or chrome?

Comment: You would also need to show that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n'(x)$$converges uniformly.

Comment: @Dave That is exactly what I'm being unable to show. I know that would suffice.

Comment: Are the summand functions defined on some compact interval?

Comment: @Dave. No. For all $\x\in {mathbb{R}}$

Comment: I don't believe the theorem that I'm thinking of will work here then. I was looking at the differentiability section here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_convergence

Comment: @Dave, You can use that theorem to show that the series above is continuously differentiable on any bounded interval, which is enough for our purpose.

Comment: @Sangchul Lee I thought of doing the same. On compact intervals. But how is that enough?

Comment: @MathMentalist Since both continuity and differentiability are local properties, you need not bother to establish them globally at once. You can establish them locally and then patch them up to provide a global result.

Comment: @Sangchul Lee I see. Thanks. :)